# Add CDATA on request's string parameter using only JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cdata

I have a jax-ws client ganerated with CXF

The request have a string-parameter (MGRequest) that contains an xml, all work's but the generated request is like this:

```
<S:Body>
   <ns5:MGRequest>&lt;mytag&gt;hello&lt;/mytag&gt;</ns5:MGRequest>
</S:Body>
```

I need to generate the body like:

```
<S:Body>
   <ns5:MGRequest><![CDATA[<mytag>hello</mytag>]]></ns5:MGRequest>
</S:Body>
```

(because i can't control the server..)

The client is like a standard jax-ws:

```
@WebService(name = "ServiceSoap")
@XmlSeeAlso({ ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface ServiceSoap {

  @WebMethod(operationName = "ProcessMessage")
  @WebResult(name = "MGResponse")
  public String processMessage(
      @WebParam(partName = "input", name = "MGRequest") String input);
}
```

And i call like this:

```
Service client = new Service(url);
client.setHandlerResolver(HandlerFactory.build(new LoggerHandler()));

ServiceSoap service = client.getServiceSoap();

String msgToSend = JaxbUtil.jaxbObjToString(xmlObj, false);
String response = service.processMessage(msgToSend);
```

I have tried adding `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CDataAdapter.class)` before `@WebParam` but the result was:

```
<S:Body>
   <ns5:MGRequest>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;mytag&gt;hello&lt;/mytag&gt;]]&gt;</ns5:MGRequest>
</S:Body>
```

Where CDataAdapter:

```
public class CDataAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return "<![CDATA[" + v + "]]>";
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to archive that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a working night i've found the solution:
adding a `javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler` to the client like this:

```
client.setHandlerResolver(HandlerFactory.build(new LoggerHandler(), new CDataHandler()));
```

where my HandlerFactory build a Handler:

```
public static HandlerResolver build(final Handler... handlers) {

    return new HandlerResolver() {
      @Override
      public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
        List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();

        if (handlers != null) {
          for (Handler handler : handlers) {
            handlerChain.add(handler);
          }
        }
        return handlerChain;
      }
    };
  }
```

---

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.Node;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class CDataHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

  @Override
  public void close(MessageContext context) {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext soapMessage) {
    try {
      SOAPMessage message = soapMessage.getMessage();
      boolean isOutboundMessage = (Boolean) soapMessage
          .get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

      // is a request?
      if (isOutboundMessage) {
        // build a CDATA NODE with the text in the root tag
        Node cddata = (Node) message.getSOAPPart().createCDATASection(
            message.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getTextContent());

        // add the CDATA's node at soap message
        message.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().appendChild(cddata);

        // remove the text tag with the raw text that will be escaped
        message.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild()
            .removeChild(message.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getFirstChild());

      }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // fail
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext soapMessage) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
  }
}
```

This is a simple class, i had only one tag with text, but in more complex scenario you can take the necessary action navigating the DOM.

Comment: The above solution to be worked you need to add "message.saveChanges();" in handleMessage message function. See https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-client-side/